# How to create a background selector that has Kitkat style for pre-Lollipop, and native one for Lollipop and above?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat, android-selector

This question is short.

How do I set a background for buttons and such, that will have the native look&feel of Lollipop (ripple etc...) for Lollipop and above, and Kitkat style for Kitkat and below?

I ask this to make this library look better:

https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/MaterialPreferenceLibrary

Answer (score 1):

I think this is possible by declaring the different 'styles' in the corresponding 'values' folder. I think the following link can help:

http://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html#Theme